# Find wordpress database in Phpadmin with google cloud platform

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

my wordpress is hosted in google cloud and i need to access my database via phpadmin to reset my password. The problem is i don't see my wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SFTP to upload Adminer (a database admin tool that is easier to use and install than phpmyadmin) or see http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password on how to reset your password without needing to access the database.

See SFTP for Google Compute Engine https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/lamp/transfer-files#sftp-compute-engine and Adminer http://www.adminer.org/